# Bootstrap list depends on the height of the screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need some help with bootstrap.
I have a long list of products and if it is longer than the height of the screen to get a roll in the two columns.
If two columns are longer than the height of the screen is to be divided into equal columns and went beyond the screen.

```
Short list:
----screen/begin------
*product1
*product2


----screen/end-------


Mid list:
----screen/begin------
*product1 *product5
*product2 *product6
*product3
*product4
----screen/end-------


Long list:
----screen/begin------
*product1 *product7 
*product2 *product8
*product3 *product9
*product4 *product10
----screen/end-------
*product5 *product11
*product6
```

Comment: Use the `{}` button to format code blocks.

Comment: Bootstrap helps format content based on the width of the screen, not the height.

Comment: sorry, this is my first question

Comment: Can you make a fiddle or bootply?